# Get item/variable from array with string AS3

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, var

so I have an array with 4 string values in it 
(defined before array like `public var p1:String` etc)

```
public var partArray:Array = 
[
    p1 = ""
    p2 = ""
    p3 = ""
    p2_3 = ""
];
```

Lets say I have a textbutton with the name of one of these variables, how would I get the correct variable from the array using the name of the textbutton.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, in AS3 it's not recomended to create associative arrays like this. For key:value maps use an `Object` (for example `{key: "value"}`) or a `Dictionary`.

With any container object you can lookup properties using array access brackets:

```
trace(myMap[key])
```

With an `Array` the `key` is an integer, with an `Object` the key is a string, and with a `Dictionary` the key is anything.

So to lookup a value by another object's name you might use:

```
myMap[myButton.name]
```